# Spring security returns 401 instead of 403

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security

I am using spring boot 3 and spring security 6. I have configured the following security chain

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(requests -> {requests
                .requestMatchers("/", "/login").permitAll(); //these urls don't require authentication
                //.anyRequest().permitAll(); //all other requests are authenticated
                requests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasRole("ADMIN");
                requests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET).hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN");
                    requests.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults()) //enable basic authentication, used for APIs
                .formLogin(form -> form  //enable form based authentication, for UI
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll());

        return http.build();
}
```

Rules configured for GET method are working fine but when I use POST method things are not working as expected.

On using POST method, I am getting 401 unauthorized error for both USER and ADMIN roles, rather In was expecting 403 error for user with role USER and access being allowed to user with role ADMIN.

Is there something wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I has to disable the csrf for POST method to work.

This is how you can do it in spring boot 3 / spring security 6

```
.csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have correctly defined the authorization rules for both GET and POST methods. The rule `requests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).hasRole("ADMIN");` specifies that only users with the "ADMIN" role can access resources using the HTTP POST method.

However, since you mentioned that you are getting a 401 unauthorized error for both USER and ADMIN roles when accessing resources using the POST method, it might be possible that user is not authenticated properly before the authorization rules are applied.

To troubleshoot this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Check if the user is being authenticated properly by printing the Authentication object in your controller or service class. You can get the authenticated user's information using the following code:

> ```
> Authentication authentication =
> SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
> System.out.println("Authenticated User: " + authentication.getName());
> ```

Check if the user has the correct roles assigned by printing the authorities of the authenticated user:

```
for (GrantedAuthority authority : authentication.getAuthorities()) {
    System.out.println(authority.getAuthority()); }
```

If the user is not being authenticated properly, check if the login page is configured correctly and if the credentials provided by the user are correct.

If the user is being authenticated properly but still unable to access the resource, you can try modifying the authorization rule for POST requests to allow all authenticated users:

```
requests.requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST).authenticated();
```

This will allow all authenticated users to access resources using the POST method. You can add logic afterward in your controller to restrict access based on the user's role.

I hope this helps!